# How to Import Component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import Header Component in App.js
but it's giving error.

```
import './App.css';
import Headers from './Components/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    </Headers>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Headers(){
 
    return (
        <div>
        Header Demo
        </div>
    );
    
}
```

Header.js file exist in src/Components

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/sanad/Documents/newapp/src/App.js: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for . (8:4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with *importing* the module.

Read the error message carefully:

> SyntaxError: /home/sanad/Documents/newapp/src/App.js: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for `<div>`.

This is because you have a closing tag (`</Headers>`) but the next element that needs to be closed in `<div>`.

Your problem is that you need to **open** the `<Headers>` element first.

```
<div>
    <Headers></Headers>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

import React from "react";
add this to App.js

Comment: That's only needed on out of date versions of React. And it wouldn't cause the error message quoted if it was the problem.